# How does $E(u)=\int E(u|v)p(v)dv$?

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I'm reading Bayesian Data Analysis: [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/)
and this equation was given

$$E(u)=\int E(u|v)p(v)dv$$

Can someone explain this to me? I don't see how they're equivalent, because to get the expectation of $u$ you need to get the average of $u$, but the RHS is the integral across all $v$, but then there could be values of $u$ not conditioned on $v$ so that means those values will be excluded will they not? Which means it's not the expectation for $u$ because it's not the weighted sum across all $u$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the simpler form of [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/en/Law_of_total_expectation), $E[u]=E[E[u|v]]$. The inside expression is a function of $v$, so it's like $E[u|v]=g(v)$, and we want $E[g(v)]$, which is $$E[u]=E[g(v)]=\int g(v)p(v)dv=\int E[u|v]p(v)dv$$

Comment: I don't think they made it clear in the book but I'm guessing $v$ is a set of sets that at independent and together make up the entire space? If that's the case then that totally make sense.

Comment: $v$ is another random variable, and we integrate over its all possibilities.